# bell behaviour in byobu

Tags: i3, notifications, byobu, libnotify

I am experimenting with bells in my wm.
for this i am using the command `sleep 3; echo -e "\a"`

Here are some different scenarios:

- running it in a terminal and changing workspace will give me an urgent alert.
- running it on another server using ssh will give me an urgent alert.

But:

- running it on another server that has byobu running does NOT give me an urgent alert.

I have googled and looked but could not find any settings in byobu on how to handle bells. Any ideas where to start to get it working even from a byobu session?

Answer (score 0):

Try typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

([source](https://major.io/2010/01/21/switching-between-audible-and-visual-bells-in-screen/))

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: Hmm, this is supposed to toggle between "visual bell" and "audible bell". You have tried triggering a bell once "audible bell" is active?

Comment: Yes. 
I use tmux as a backend, could that have anything to do with this?

Comment: yes! tmux and byobu essentially do the same thing, I would try using only one or the other.

Comment: @dwurf this is not entirely true: Byobu is a wrapper for tmux OR screen, this can be chosen within byobu. When installed correctly byobu starts and handles all when you manually start screen / tmux. Make sure you do not use tmux and screen simultaneously, as that would give complications.

Comment: addon: Byobu helps preventing users to mix tmux and screen, as that would give complications